# Select form value using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

So here's a part of a form that I'm printing out using PHP:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1" checked/>
```

I need to pass the value to JavaScript but that doesn't seem to be working right now. Here's what I'm using:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          var val = $(this).val();
          switch(val)
          {
            case(1):
                alert("Value 1");
                break;
            case(2):
                alert("Value 2");
                break;
            case(3):
                alert("Value 3");
                break;
          }

         });
```

UPDATE:

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
    foreach($a as $b) {
        if ($s["id"]== $b["c"]) {
            if($b["p"] == "e") {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1" checked/></td>';
            }else {

                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1"/></td>';
            }   
            if($b["p"] == "r") {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="2" checked/></td>';
            }else {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="2"/></td>';
            }
            if($b["p"] == "b") {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="3" checked/></td>';
            }else {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="3"/></td>';
            }
        }else {
            echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1"/></td>';
            echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="2"/></td>';
            echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="3"/></td>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: can we see what the <input tag looks like once parsed by php ?

Comment: I'm just echoing the value from an external source like this:  echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1" checked/></td>';

Comment: check `}` you missed one.

Comment: Why is that tagged `php`?

Comment: `alert()`is like pain in the ahhhh, did you hear about `console.log("message");` already? This will log to your e.g. firebug console in Firefox.